# Sitecore 9.2 Unit Test Error: Could not find configuration node: contentSearch/configuration

Tags: unit-testing

I am trying to configure a Unit Test project within my Feature directory i.e.

- Feature

  - Activity

    - ExampleProject
    - ExampleProject.UnitTest

**Implementation**

- In Unit Test Project: UnitTest.cs [TestMethod]

```
    {
      string val1= "Search";
      string val2= "en";
      string expectedVal = "xyz"; 

      string retVal = new Test.GetItem(val1, val2);
      Assert.AreEqual(expectedVal, retVal);
    }
```

- In Implementation Class

```
public string GetItem(str1, str2)
{
List<SearchResultItem> matches;

     --BREAKS HERE-- using (var context = ContentSearchManager.GetIndex("sitecore_web_index").CreateSearchContext()) 
      {
        var predicate = PredicateBuilder.True<SearchResultItem>();

        predicate = predicate.And(p => p.Path.StartsWith("/sitecore/system/Dictionary"));
        predicate = predicate.And(p => p.str1== str2);

        matches = context.GetQueryable<SearchResultItem>().Where(predicate).ToList();
      }
}
```

I believe I have all necessary dependencies referenced (Sitecore.Kernel, Sitecore.Mvc, Sitecore.ContentSearch) but I am still getting error: `Could not find configuration node: contentSearch/configuration`. I have local IIS instance of my Sitecore site working where GetItem(str1, str2) is being called multiple times so not sure why a Unit Test project won't run properly.

**Versions**

- Sitecore 9.2
- .NET 4.7.2

Do I still have to make changes to config to allow for Unit Test?

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you are writing unit test. Unit test means that you testing some piece of code without dependencies on data. But in your case, you using Sitecore Content Search

```
using (var context = ContentSearchManager.GetIndex("sitecore_web_index").CreateSearchContext())
```

But unit tests are executed in separate sandbox, they don't know anything about Sitecore. It is expected that configuration for index is not found.

You need to mock context:

```
var searchContext = Substitute.For<IProviderSearchContext>();
var queryable = new LuceneProviderQueryableStub(enumerable);
searchContext.GetQueryable().Returns(queryable);
```

And stub implementation:

```
    public class LuceneProviderQueryableStub<TElement> : IOrderedQueryable<TElement>, IOrderedQueryable, IQueryProvider
    {
        private readonly EnumerableQuery<TElement> innerQueryable;

        public Type ElementType { get { return ((IQueryable)innerQueryable).ElementType; } }

        public Expression Expression { get { return ((IQueryable)innerQueryable).Expression; } }

        public IQueryProvider Provider { get { return this; } }

        public LuceneProviderQueryableStub(IEnumerable<TElement> enumerable)
        {
            innerQueryable = new EnumerableQuery<TElement>(enumerable);
        }

        public LuceneProviderQueryableStub(Expression expression)
        {
            innerQueryable = new EnumerableQuery<TElement>(expression);
        }

        public IQueryable CreateQuery(Expression expression)
        {
            return new LuceneProviderQueryableStub<TElement>((IEnumerable<TElement>)((IQueryProvider)innerQueryable).CreateQuery(expression));
        }

        public IQueryable<TElement1> CreateQuery<TElement1>(Expression expression)
        {
            return (IQueryable<TElement1>)new LuceneProviderQueryableStub<TElement>((IEnumerable<TElement>)((IQueryProvider)innerQueryable).CreateQuery(expression));
        }

        public object Execute(Expression expression)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public TResult Execute<TResult>(Expression expression)
        {
            var items = this.ToArray();
            object results = new SearchResults<TElement>(items.Select(s => new SearchHit<TElement>(0, s)), 0);
            return (TResult)results;
        }

        public IEnumerator<TElement> GetEnumerator()
        {
            return ((IEnumerable<TElement>)innerQueryable).GetEnumerator();
        }

        IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
        {
            return GetEnumerator();
        }
    }
```

Also you should not call getting index directly

```
ContentSearchManager.GetIndex("sitecore_web_index").CreateSearchContext()
```

you need wrapper that will return IProviderSearchContext: real in Sitecore context, fake in unit test context.

Then your unit test could start to work. See [this gist](https://gist.github.com/vivianroberts/1a632d8bfb8fa62e23c4679b086728ce) for working example.

P.S. But your unit test in meaning of unit testing doesn't have sense. Unit test should test logic(code), but not data.

Comment: Thanks for the descriptive answer. I figured you cannot access Sitecore context without via Unit Test.

Comment: @LinkedListT yes, if you want to test code that depends on Sitecore Context you need to mock it.

Comment: is there any method attaching Unit test project to iis sitecore instance? My goal is to have automated testing configured on azure pipelines for build processes